# How can I merge duplicate accounts on Booking.com

Tags: account-management, user-accounts, booking.com

I have accidentally had two accounts on Booking.com.  On the first one, I misspelled by email address (swapped two characters).  They obviously never confirmed it the email address.  I have bookings on both as one browser auto-fills one address and another browser auto-fills in the other.

The main issue is that the new bookings I have just made are on the incorrect email account, so I don't receive notifications.  The obvious thing would be to merge the accounts.  I can not find any way to do this, nor can I find any way to send booking a message.

**How can I get my accounts merged ?**

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Booking.com resources for end-users to learn if an account merge is something that end-users could do. If there isn't a specific resource, look for information about how to contact Booking.com support.

Things that you might try on your own:

1. Try to add an alternate email address.
2. Try to update the misspelled email address by using a different one (not used for sign-up on Booking.com).
3. Try to share the Bookings done with the misspelled account with a verified account.

---

As of February 23, 2024 the Booking.com homepage has a lot of links to resources near the page bottom, a couple of links have the text **Customer Service Help**.

[image: Booking.com home page section about resources]

Those links point to https://secure.booking.com/help. The page heading is "Welcome to the Help Center".